# "this" is undefined inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {isAuthenticated} from "../../helpers/auth_utils";

const PrivateRoute = ({component, ...rest}) => {
    //TODO how these two component's are different?
    let {component: Component, ...componentProps} = this.props;

    return (<Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return <Component component={component} {...componentProps}/>;
        } else {
            return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>;
        }
    }
    }/>);
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

It's strange that `this` is undefined in this component. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've used arrow function, which doesn't have its own, isolated scope. In this case, you should expect props in arguments of your function, so { ...rest, component } is you properties in real.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functinos don't have their own `this`. They get the scope that's above them, here the scope is Window, but in strict mode javascript doesn't want accidental use of `window`, so they make it undefined. Thus `this` is undefined.

You can try wrapping `PrivateRoute` into a class, and you will see that then `this` would be the class.

To have your function create it's own context, you need to change it from arrow function to regular one.

`const PrivateRoute = function({component, ...rest}) {`

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don’t have their “own” `this`. When you reference `this` from such a function, it’s taken from the outer “normal” function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

```
let user = {
  firstName: "Arian",
  sayHi() {
    let arrow = () => alert(this.firstName);
    arrow();
  }
};

user.sayHi(); // Arian
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword does not refers to arrow function. It refers to regular function.

In your case, you can do some thing like this

`const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    //TODO how these two component's are different?
    let {component: Component, ...componentProps} = props;`

Make sure `component` and `componentProps` are available in props.